# Can't save credentials in Finder for server connection

Tags: mac, nas, finder

We have several accounts on a Mac. Each has its own account on a NAS as well connected locally via SMB.
I want to pair these on the Mac, but somehow, for example, in my account, it shows different NAS user credentials belonging to the other OSX account. (only the user name, not the password)
I want to add these volumes to the login items in every Mac account not to type all these credentials every morning, but it doesn't work in one account, but it is working in the other.

Where are these credentials stored? (couldn't find in keychain) How can I avoid this problem?